# Counter cache column in PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql, caching

In my database I have `tasks` and `comments` tables. Each task has many comments.

I'd like to create `tasks.comments_count` column that would be updated automatically by PostgreSQL, so I can get `comments_count` (and sort / filter by it) in O(1) time while selecting all tasks.

I know there are language-specific solutions like [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) of ActiveRecord, but I don't want to use them (I find them fragile). I'd like PostgreSQL to take care of such counter caches.

I also know PostgreSQL supports triggers, but they are hard to write and use (not a solid solution)

Ideally it would be a PostgreSQL extension or some native feature I'm not aware of.

Lazy calculation of such counters would be a great bonus.

Comment: Why not just count the number of comments for each task in a query instead of having to maintain that figure in a database table? One other option may be to use triggers and update the `tasks.comments_count` with each new comment that is added or deleted.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I provided a simple to understand example. In real application there are multiple counters, and need for advanced sorting / filtering / grouping by them, so counting associated records in query is not a performant solution. Let's say it's a client requirement to store counter cache in the table.

Comment: I've not encountered "counter cache" before but, as mentioned, I'd probably just do this with a trigger on insert/delete of comments if you want to move the performance hit to writes rather than reads. It's also a portable solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "[triggers] are hard to write and use (not a solid solution)"? Triggers aren't any harder to write or use than anything else. And what do you mean by "lazy calculation"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want Postgres to automatically do something on the basis of an insert/update/delete - i.e. if you want this operation to *trigger* some other action - then you need to write a trigger.

It's pretty straightforward. Simple enough that I doubt anyone would bother creating an extension (let alone a language feature) to save you the trouble. And it's certainly simpler (and as you pointed out, safer) than whatever ActiveRecord has going on under the hood.

Something like this is generally all it takes (I haven't tested this, so you might want to do so...):

```
CREATE FUNCTION maintain_comment_count_trg() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP IN ('UPDATE', 'DELETE') THEN
    UPDATE tasks SET comment_count = comment_count - 1 WHERE id = old.task_id;
  END IF;
  IF TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN
    UPDATE tasks SET comment_count = comment_count + 1 WHERE id = new.task_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER maintain_comment_count
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF task_id OR DELETE ON comments
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE maintain_comment_count_trg();
```

If you want it to be airtight, you'd need an additional trigger for `TRUNCATE`s on `comments`; whether it's worth the trouble is up to you.

To handle updates to a `tasks.id` value which is being referenced (either via deferred constraints or `ON UPDATE` actions) then there's a bit more to it, but this is an uncommon case.

And if your client library / ORM is naive enough to send through every field in every `UPDATE` statement, you may want a separate `UPDATE` trigger which fires only when the value has actually changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maintain_comment_count_update
AFTER UPDATE OF task_id ON comments
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (old.task_id IS DISTINCT FROM new.task_id)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE maintain_comment_count_trg();
```

Comment: Hello Nick, can you please explain necessity of `WHEN (old.task_id IS DISTINCT FROM new.task_id)`

Comment: @lessless: I've updated my answer to explain this a little better.

Comment: Thank you! Pushing CC down to the database level is a very, very sane option :)

Comment: doesn't work :( it says the function reached the end without a `RETURN`

Comment: @NickBarnes it needs a `DECLARE` and a `RETURN`

Comment: @brauliobo: Thanks, added the `RETURN`. No need for a `DECLARE`, there are no variables in there.

Comment: I want to hit the trigger after the transaction. I read it here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html but i dont understand how i can use `constraint` as deferred here.

Comment: @Ahmad: If you use `CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` and add the `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` clause, then the trigger should fire at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Ok i tried it but not working for me. i have posted my question here if you can take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925529/run-trigger-after-transaction-postgresql-9-6